# Receiving 504 gateway timeout error when trying to access end point deployed on AWS

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services, asp.net-web-api2

I developed an application using asp.net Web API and it is deployed on AWS.

When the host is trying to make a call to my end point, it is receiving a 504 gateway time out error intermittently. I wrote logs for each and every function, to determine if any method is being hit, but it looks like the application is not being hit.

Did anyone encounter these kind of issues ?

Comment: Are you making a http call or https call? And are you using a ELB or just a EC2 instance?

Comment: The end user is calling my end point and it is a http call since it is hosted in QA environment. Also it is just a EC2 instance

Comment: Is your Port 80 open in security group?

Comment: Yes, port 80 is open